# PrincipalContext: How do I get the full LDAP context path from only providing an OU?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, account-management

I'd like to increase speed for finding users in a query similar to this:

```cs
using (PrincipalContext pc = PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
using (UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(pc) { SamAccountName = $"*{search}*" })
using (PrincipalSearcher ps = PrincipalSearcher(up))
{
  ...
}
```

Currently, the query searches the whole directory, taking a very long time.

I'd like to constrain the context to a specific container, but **I only now a single portion of this container.**

So, for instance, from a full LDAP path like this: `OU=a,OU=b,OU=c,dc=d,dc=e,dc=loc` I only have `OU=b`.

How can I retrieve the full LDAP path for using it in the `context` portion of the `PrincipalContext` constructor by using a class from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` having only a fraction of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is this: `SamAccountName = $"*{search}*"`

Specifically, the `*` at the beginning. The `sAMAccountName` attribute is indexed, so it is normally a very fast query. But since you have a wildcard at the beginning, it cannot use the index in this search. That means it has to look at *every user* in your domain to try and find a match.

If you can change that to `$"{search}*"`, your problems will go away.

But to answer your actual question,

> I'd like to constrain the context to a specific container, but I only now a single portion of this container.

If you really want to go through this, you will have to perform a search to find the OU and read the `distinguishedName` for it. You can't do it with `PrincipalSearcher` since the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace just doesn't have any class for OUs. You will have to use [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=netframework-4.8) directly (which is what `PrincipalSearcher` uses in the background anyway). It would look something like this:

```
var ouName = "b";
var search = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry()) {
    Filter = $"(&(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(name={ouName}))"
};
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
var ou = search.FindOne();
var ouDn = ou.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
```

Then you can use `ouDn` as the base path for your user search.

Comment: Thank you for this great piece of information! ... I comprehend, the query I'm using is pretty slow, but that's what the customer requested. That's why I'm looking for a way to speed things up while keeping functionality.